How to connect via SSL to windows local development website?
I've got a local development website that can be accesses as http://castle. After generating certificates, etc., attempts to access as https://castle fail - without discoverable errors. What am I missing?
Here's what's done so far:
Environment:

Windows 10 build 19045.5247
.\httpd -v: Server version: Apache/2.4.62 (Win64)
.\httpd -t: Syntax OK

Apache error log used to warn about SSLSessionCache. Although I could find nothing with that name in a conf file, I loaded every module that included cache. The warning disappeared.
All .conf modules noted in http-ssl.conf were confirmed to be loaded.
SSL certificates were created and installed based on this.
castle vhost:
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName  castle

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "G:\workspace\castle\castle.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "G:\workspace\castle\castle.key"
    
    DocumentRoot "G:\workspace\castle"
    <Directory "G:\workspace\castle">
        Options +Includes
        DirectoryIndex  index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

What's known:
Chrome: http://castle
Site launches as intended. Contains only html, cs, js.
Chrome: https://castle
This site can’t be reached
castle refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off makes no difference
Apache access.log example: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2024:13:55:06 -0800] "-" 408 -
Apache error.log is empty
Firefox: Unable to connect...

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means the service rejected the connection.  The server logs should indicate the true issue.

As noted above, the Apache access log shows a 408 error. What would you suggest? With the site being local, it's hard to see where there could be significant delays in response.

It does not appear you have Apache configured to handle (bind) 127.0.0.1, just castle. Is the reason you don't have a TDL, even if it's something made up like .local? Do you understand that even if you generate self-signed TLS and "install" it, Chrome and Firefox will both complain about the certificate?

I'm probably misunderstanding your comment, but it led me to make a step forward. I added Listen 443 to httpd.conf. That led to a warning about not being secure but did allow the site to load.

Best you can do since a self-signed certificate signed by a self-signed root CA is indeed “not secure” according to the guidelines.

Thank you. I'll gladly accept a relevant answer.

You are in the best position to self-answer your question

Issue resolved by adding Listen 443 to httpd.conf. And why do this at all? Just wanted to know that I could.
